# Как сбросить значения в EditText имея аттрибут save instance state?

Tags: java, android

Вопрос: Есть активити, в нем несколько `EditText` с атрибутом `save instance state`, но мне нужно, чтобы в нескольких информация сбрасывалась при повороте экрана, как это сделать?

Я попробовал использовал для двух `EditText` `android:freezesText="false"`, но это не помогло, они не сбрасывают введеный значения при повороте экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Если в разметке xml у твоего EditText установлен id, то текст в нем будет сохраняться, можешь попробовать в методе onResume() чистить поля

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    editText.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте:

```
android:freezesText="true"
```

Comment: Извините, я не корректно задал вопрос, я его поправил, не могли бы вы взглянуть на правленую версию.

Comment: @Nikolai, приложите код